# javascript if else nested go to the upper if

Tags: javascript, if-statement, nested

Is there a way to go to the else of the `if/else` statement 1 level higher?

say i have a construction like this (simple example of what i want to do):

```
function yada(data) {
   if(typeof data !== 'undefined') {
      data = parser.parseData(data);
      if(!data) {
         // from here i want to go to the else statement 1 level higher
      }
      else {
         alert('all is well');
      }
   }
   else {
      alert('not parsed');
   } 
}
```

Comment: You can merely restructure your `if..else` flow so that the same case is triggered; you can not jump around inside a structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that, instead you need to reconstruct the `if...else` as following

```
function yada(data) {
   if(typeof data !== 'undefined' && data = parser.parseData(data)) {
      alert('all is well');
   }
   else {
      alert('not parsed');
   } 
}
```

Comment: alright and what if i need data to be a specific value would that still work in a construction like this?

Comment: im just wondering say the parser returns an object with error messages instead of false would i be able to put another statement like && typeof data.error == 'undefined' would that work or how would be the best way to go about it?

Comment: allright thx, this was what i was looking for i knew i could make it abit cleaner just couldn't come up with it :P